# Adding custom metadata to pdfs

Tags: linux, pdf, metadata

I'm currently trying to organize my files and one thing that would be useful is adding metadata to all my pdfs (to other document types would be useful too) so I can search through them easily.  But the title and author tags aren't quite enough.  Is there any way to add custom tags like subtitle, edition, volume, original publication date, etc to pdf files?  Bonus points if it also works on djvu files.

Forgot to mention: I'm running Linux Mint and so can't run Adobe Reader/ Acrobat (... well I suppose I could with Wine but I'd prefer a native solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In adobe for example you should be able to go into `File -> Properties -> Custom` and add the tags you would like. I do not know if it works for djvu files though.

Edit for Linux:
Master PDF Editor should be able to do it. I see [here](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor-help/document-properties/#document-info) in Document Properties you can specify keywords of your own that correspond to information in the file.

Comment: See the edit to my question.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found pdfarranger [github](https://github.com/jeromerobert/pdfarranger).  I didn't get a chance to try it because it depends on a python-poppler gobect interface that is only packaged on debian/arch/fedora(?).

This answer [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489230/where-is-metadata-for-pdf-files-can-i-insert-metadata-into-any-pdf-file) shows a few ways to do it with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late but maybe pdftk might be used for things like that. An example is shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554159/how-to-add-more-metadata-to-a-pdf-file-so-i-have-more-info.

Description of pdftk can be found in https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/pdftk/.